# Notification images appear in Google Photos backup

Tags: notifications, google-photos, google-backup

Why are images that appear in my notifications starting to appear in my Google Photos? How do I stop it?

Comment: Can you open the Photos app and go to Settings - Backup & Sync, then Device Folders and check what is ticked? What app is putting images in your notifications, that app's folder is likely being backed up or you set that app to save it's images to a folder that is being backed up.

Comment: Many apps are starting to put pics in the notifications, Groupon, Reddit, Trulia, etc. For backup I only have Photos selected, nothing for any apps. I don't think the notification photos are stored on the device because when I open Device Folders in the Photos app I don't see the pics in any folder.

Comment: Gotcha... So in Photo, tap one of these pictures to view it, then press the 3-dot menu button and select Info, that should show you where the file is stored. Photo is a Gallery replacement, it will display pictures from any folder that does not contain the empty file `.nomedia` in it. Are they being backed up as well?

Comment: Yeah this kind-of confirms what I was thinking. Pictures that are stored on my phone do show the path to the folder. The pics are not on the phone (stored in the cloud) only have the file name. These pics that came from notifications only have the file name, so they are not stored on the phone. No, the only pics being backed up are the photos I take and these notification images.